# Classic asp contact form

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

Hi I am trying to create a contact form with custom html and asp, and the only problem that I know very little programming in particular ASP could you help me ????

I tried to create some examples but I understood very little

My code HTML

```
<body>
<form id="contactform" action="contact.asp" method="POST">
<div class="formcolumn">
<label for="nome">Nome e Cognome</label>
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
<label for="indirizzo">Indirizzo - cap - località - provincia</label>
<input type="text" id="indirizzo" name="indirizzo" />
<ul>
<li>Consegna a Domicilio<input type="radio" id="domicilio" name="luogo" value="consegna a domicilio" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="formcolumn">
<label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
<input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" />
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
<ul>
<li>Ritiro presso la macelleria<input type="radio" id="macelleria" name="luogo" value="ritiro presso la macelleria" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="formcolumn_2">
<label for="consegna">Indirizzo di consegna (compilare solo nel caso di consegna a domicilio)</label>
<input type="text" id="consegna" name="consegna" />
<label for="ordine">Ordine</label>
<textarea id="ordine" name="ordine" ></textarea>
<ul class="campo_dati">
<p>Info dati</p>
<li>Campo_1<input type="radio" id="Campo_1" name="dati" value="campo_1" /></li>
<li>Campo_2<input type="radio" id="Campo_2" name="dati" value="campo_2" /></li>
<li>Campo_3<input type="radio" id="Campo_3" name="dati" value="campo_3" /></li>
<li>Campo_4<input type="radio" id="Campo_4" name="dati" value="campo_4" /></li>
<li>Campo_5<input type="radio" id="Campo_5" name="dati" value="campo_5" /></li>
<li>Campo_6<input type="radio" id="Campo_6" name="dati" value="campo_6" /></li>
<li>Campo_7<input type="radio" id="Campo_7" name="dati" value="campo_7" /></li>
<li>Campo_8<input type="radio" id="Campo_8" name="dati" value="campo_8" /></li>
</ul>
<label for="specifiche">Altre informazioni</label>
<input type="text" id="specifiche" name="specifiche" />
<ul class="campo_dati">
<p>Accettazione condizioni</p>
<li>Ho letto e accettato il regolamento e le condizioni sulla privacy<input type="radio" id="accettazione" name="accettazione" value="accettazione" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<input class="button" value="invia" type="submit" name="invia" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

my css

```
#contactform{

    width: 585px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.formcolumn input, #contactform textarea{
    width:95%;
    border: 2px solid #D6C27A;

    padding: 4px;
}

.formcolumn_2 input, #contactform textarea{
    width:571px;
    border: 2px solid #D6C27A;
    padding: 4px;
}

#contactform textarea{
    resize:vertical; /* allow vertical resize of textarea */
    height: 200px;
}

#contactform input[type="radio"]{
    width: auto;
    float:right;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#contactform .formcolumn{ /* column div inside form */
    width:280px;
    float: left;
}

#contactform .formcolumn:first-of-type{
    margin-right: 25px; /* 2% margin after first column */
}

#contactform label { 
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    display: block;
}

#contactform ul{
    list-style:none;
    list-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

#contactform ul li{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#contactform div.buttons{
    clear: both;
    text-align:right;
}

#contactform input.button{
    width: 85px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 1.5EM;
    border: 3px solid #D6C27A;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    cursor: pointer;
    color: #AC8100;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    background: url(Sito/images/botton.png);
}

#contactform input.button:active{
    color: white;
    background: url(Sito/images/botton_hover.png);
}

#contactform input.button{
    text-align: center;
}

.campo_dati p {
    margin-top: 30px;   
}

.campo_dati input[type="radio"]{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#contactform .campo_dati li {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
```

and this is the classic asp I have create

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>

    <% 
    nome = request.Form("nome")
    indirizzo = request.Form("indirizzo")
    telefono = request.Form("telefono")
    email = request.Form("email")

    ordine = request.Form("ordine")


    ' istanza di CDO.Message
    set CDOmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

CDOmail.To = "tariccopaolo@alice.it"
CDOmail.From = "smtp.tuodominio.it"
CDOmail.Subject = "Nuovo ordine"
```

You know help me finish the ASP file so that it works by connecting the radio bottom????

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We don't write code for you here, rather we're here to help with programming specific problems.  If you have a specific problem connecting the radio buttons, please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic Classic ASP email form to which you can add your own html and css to make it look prettier.  There are some other parameters you may need to add depending on the location and configuration of your SMTP server.

You can have asp and the html in separate files, as you've done, if you prefer, but I find having it all in the one file makes things easier, particularly when you start adding server side verification and you want to send the user back to the form if he misses a field, enters an invalid email address etc.

```
<%
If request("submit") <> "" Then
Set objEMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEMail.To = "you@yourdomain.com"
objEMail.From = Request("name")& "<" & Request("from") & ">"
objEMail.ReplyTo = Request("from")
objEMail.Subject = Request("subject")
objEMail.TextBody = Request("message")  
objEMail.Send()
Set objEMail = Nothing
%>
<html>
<body>
<h3>Thank you for your message</h3>
</body>
</html>
<% Else %>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<label>Email address:</label><input type="text" name="from" /><br />
<label>Subject:</label><input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
<label>Message:</label><textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
<% End If %>
```

You can't invent your own properties for a CDO.Message object, the properties which you can use correspond to the fields of an email message, ie From, To, Subject, TextBody, HTMLBody, CC, BCC etc.

You can use multiple form fields in TextBody or HTMLBody, so instead of

```
objEMail.Indirizzo = Request("indirizzo")
objEMail.Telefono = Request("telefono")
objEMail.Email = Request("email")
objEMail.Consegna = Request("consegna")
objEMail.Specifiche = Request("specifiche")
```

You should have something like

```
 objEMail.TextBody = "Indirizzo:" & Request("indirizzo") & vbcrlf & "Telephono:" & Request("telefono")  & vbcrlf & "Email:" & Request("email") & vbcrlf & Request("consegna") & vbcrlf & Request("specifiche")
```

vbcrlf is to put line breaks in your text message.

To retrieve the selected value from your radio button list you would use `Request("dati")`

I recommend this page http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Edit 2

Re the link you've provided at paulindustry.altervista.org/contact_form_2.html - a few points

1. Obviously you need to give it a .asp extension for it to function as an asp page.
2. You need to close the quotes after the objEmail to value (my mistake)
   `objEMail.To = "you@yourdomain.com"`
3. You need to add `<% End if %>` at the very end of your page
4. If there's nothing in your form to populate the Subject field then probably best to use something like `objEMail.Subject = "Form Submission"`, which will result in the title of the email you receive being "Form Submission".  Emails with no title are often caught by spam filters.
5. Just add your radio button field to objEmail.Textbody, eg

   `objEMail.TextBody = "Indirizzo:" & Request("indirizzo") & vbcrlf & Telephono:" & Request("telefono")  & vbcrlf & "Email:" & Request("email") & vbcrlf & "Consegna:" & Request("consegna") & vbcrlf & "Specifiche:" & Request("specifiche") & vbcrlf & "Dati:" & Request("dati")`
6. For agreeing to terms and conditions, a checkbox field might be more useful that a radio button field containing one button.

Comment: if you is not too much to ask to show me some examples with radio bottom.
I went on

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_radiob

  I found a similar ple but I did not understand com do when I connect it sends the email

Comment: I corrected the code but the problem remains.
Also since I subjct the field do not have it I can take it off ???

You place a link to the page on which I loaded the form to see if it works

Comment: The w3schools example you  provide doesn't send an email, it just displays the form submission values on the next page